# Ошибка при компиляции простейшего Qt примера

Tags: makefile, qt, c++, linux

Прошу не пинайте и не тычите пальцем - я зеленый как зеленка нуб.

Взял дистр дебиана 6.0.6, установил на виртуалку, запустил консоль. Установил Qt из репов.
[Тут](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/algol/Qt/developing-applications-qt-part-1.html) неплохой вроде урок про него. Но запуск утилиты **make** для сборки первого примера, заканчивается ошибкой:

```
root@postgresql /home/test# qmake -project
root@postgresql /home/test# qmake
root@postgresql /home/test# make
    g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o first.o first.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o test first.o -L/usr/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
gcc first.o all -o first
gcc: all: No such file or directory
make: *** [first] Error 1
```

Перелопатил туториал, полазил по сайте Qt - так и не нашел ответа - может поможете?
Я начинающий в Линуксе...

Comment: а dev пакеты установили?

Comment: вроде apt-get install qt-sdk
или недостаточно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспроизвёл твою ситуацию в чруте с таким же дебианом. Похоже, что имеется баг в qmake. При  генерации Makefile он генеририрует в нём правило вида: `first: all`.

Что ведёт к печальным последствиям в случае, если имя файла с исходником `first.cpp`. 
У тебя файл с исходником так и называется. Возьми его переименуй во что-нибудь типа `test.cpp` и подправь .pro файл. После этого должно заработать.

```
$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o test.o test.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o test test.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
$ ./test 
Hello world
```

Comment: спасибо... даже интересно стало... кстати, интереса ради - а код в первом примере у тебя выводит что-то на консоль?

Comment: стоп... нашел - не просто "test" а "./test"... так что поздравьте меня - дефлорация прошла...)

Comment: Только называть свою программу `test` не очень хорошо в  \*nix-ах. 

Дело в том, что есть команда /usr/bin/test, которая будет вызвана, если случайно набрать test, а не ./test. 

Потом можно долго чесать затылок...

Comment: @avp а если не секрет что делает эта команда "test"?

Comment: @Rules почитайте [тут](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html), какбэ основы шелл скриптинга ;)

Comment: @Rules, `man test`


    NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

    DESCRIPTION
       Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION.

вызванная без аргументов делает exit(1).