# Ошибка при компиляции любого проекта Qt

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

Доброго времени суток всем.

В Qt я - новичок. Установил Qt 5.4, беру примеры из сети, пробую компилировать любой пример "по уставу":

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

Первые две команды проходят без проблем, третья - ВСЕГДА выдает одну и ту же ошибку:

> d:\Qt\Project\Samples\firstsample>make
>   make -f Makefile.Release
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, make -f Makefile.Release, ...) failed.
>   make (e=2): Не удается найти указанный файл.
>   make: *** [release] Error 2

Текст программы - из примера:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
int main(int argv, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argv, args);
    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Не прошу сделать ЗА меня, прошу хотя бы подсказать, в чем может быть проблема и как ее победить?

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164349/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-qt-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) прочитал, что под дебианом есть баг qmake.
У меня Win-7 полная, 64 бит. Может, и здесь то же самое?

**Обновление**

Извиняюсь, ошибка в ссылке. [Правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164349/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-qt-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0):
[Ошибка при компиляции простейшего Qt примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164349/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-qt-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

**Обновление**

Файл называется firstsample.cpp.
Взял пример [отсюда](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html)

Добавил в проект такую же строку (QT+=widgets), ошибка не пропала, но изменилась- Error 3:

> Could not find qmake configuration file win32-msvc2013.

**Обновление**

По последней ссылке - Фиолетовый Жираф пишет:

> Removing Qt 5.3 altogether and installing it from scratch solved the issue.

Уже, сделал (поставил 5.4.0). Не помогло. "ПилИте, Шура, пилИте..."

**Дополнение**

Не смог добавить комментарий (ограничено их количество), поэтому пишу сюда.

MSVC на компьютере не установлена, программа nmake.exe - отсутствует.

Борландовский make.exe дает ошибку:

> FORCE not found, don't know, what to do with them.

(или что-то вроде этого).

Скачал * Make-3.81 for Windows * с sourceforge.net, отсюда.

Застряло в памяти, из какого-то описания установки Qt, что хорошо бы установить и компонент ZIP; но в последних загрузчиках - нет его упоминания.
Вручную отредактировал файлы Makefile.Debug и Makefile.Release, в обоих убрал строку

> ZIP           = zip -r -9

а также раздел после

> dist:

(там начинается с $(ZIP) )

Не знаю, может это пляска с бубном, но проект и собрался, и запускается (и говорит "Хэллоу").

Получается, действительно, баг qmake: нет проверки, установлен ли компонент ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

Потестил под федорой 21. Тут есть и 4 и 5 Qt. Для 4 отработало без проблем. Для 5 пришлось в pro файл добавить строку

```
QT += widgets
```

А как называется Ваш cpp файл?

**Обновление**

[Тут](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/44292) пишут, что это ошибка в qmake, там захардкорен путь.

**Обновление**

А студия установлена? А то оно хочет использовать студийный компилятор.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток! Уточните, каким компилятором Вы пользуетесь для сборки проекта? Если Вы используете Microsoft Visual C++, то команда *make* неверна, вместо нее надо использовать *nmake*. Проверьте также, что путь к утилитам Вашего компилятора добавлен в системную переменную **Path**.

P.S. Судя по предоставленной Вами ошибке, дело именно в этом.